# jQuery append() is broken in IE?

Tags: jquery

Is jQuery 1.6.4 `append()` is broken in IE?

This code works everywhere but IE6+

```
$('<xml></xml>').append('<test>hello world</test>');
```

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: `<xml></xml>` is not a selector, so what is it appending to?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: it fails with an error - "An unexpected method call or property access. Check line 3 in jquery.min.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> **jQuery( html, [ownerDocument] )**
>
> html A string of HTML to create on the fly. Note that this parses HTML,
>   not XML.

The argument passed to jQuery is not HTML(there is no html-element `xml`) so there will be nothing to append something to.

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for informations about creation of XML-Documents in IE<9

Comment: ok, so that means i can't write xml with jquery? (despite it works everywhere but ie)?

Comment: Yes, jQuery doesn't provide a cross-browser implementation for creating XML-docs from a fragment.

Comment: Thanks. But… there is really no way to rewrite this code with jQuery?

Comment: You may create a plugin using the existing methods(the one linked above for IE and for other browsers use the DOM-> http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document ), maybe somebody already created such a plugin.